# Django Form values without HTML escape

Tags: python, django-forms, currency, symbols

I need to set the Django forms.ChoiceField to display the currency symbols. Since django forms escape all the HTML ASCII characters, I can't get the  &#36; ( **€** ) or the &pound; ( **£** ) to display the currency symbol.

```
<select id="id_currency" name="currency">
    <option value="&amp;#36;">&#36;</option>
    <option value="&amp;pound;">&pound;</option>
    <option value="&amp;euro;">&euro;</option>
</select>
```

Could you suggest any methods to display the actual HTML Currency character at least for the value part of the option?

```
<select name="currency" id="id_currency">
    <option value="&amp;#36;">$</option>
    <option value="&amp;pound;">£</option>
    <option value="&amp;euro;">€</option>
</select>
```

**Update:**
Please note I use **Django 0.96** as my application is running on Google App Engine.
And the ***<SELECT>*** above is rendered using Django Forms.

```
currencies = (('&#36;', '&#36;'), 
              ('&pound;', '&pound;'), 
              ('&euro;', '&euro;'))    
currency = forms.ChoiceField(choices=currencies, required=False)
```

Thanks,
***Arun.***

Comment: Are you using a custom template or use the django-admin?

Comment: I am using a custom template.

Comment: Other way is to use unicode u'\u20AC'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use "[safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#how-to-turn-it-off)" in the template or "[mark_safe](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping)" in the view,
turn off autoescaping in the template, 
or use Unicode characters instead of HTML entities in your form.

**Using `mark_safe`**

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

currencies = ((mark_safe('&#36;'), mark_safe('&#36;')), 
              (mark_safe('&pound;'), mark_safe('&pound;')), 
              (mark_safe('&euro;'), mark_safe('&euro;')))
```

**Using `autoescape off`**

As an alternative in your template you can [turn off escaping for a block of code](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#for-template-blocks).
Everything between tags `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}`
will not be escaped.

**Using Unicode characters**

When nothing else works try the following. In the file that contains your currencies tuple put the following line as the very first or second line:

```
# coding=utf-8
```

and then in your currencies tuple put the actual unicode characters:

```
currencies = (('$', '$'), 
              ('£', '£'), 
              ('€', '€'))
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the quick reply.
But I don't how either of this can be applied in the case of django Forms.
To Add: I should have mentioned that I use Django 0.96 as my application runs on Google's App Engine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again for the reply. I use Django 0.96 as my application runs on Google's App Engine. As far as I can understand django.utils.safestring was introduced after 0.96

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. But again the problem will be the version of Django I am using 0.96. I think only Django 1.0 has the "autoescape" tag. It's times like these I wish I had Django 1.0. But changing the version now will be a very large overhead, since I am in Google App Engine.